# how to simulate odom with Gazebo

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

I've got my urdf file with differential drive.
The file is very similar to [this](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2_tutorials/blob/master/sam_bot_description/src/description/sam_bot_description.urdf)

I would like to simulate Odom values while using Nav2 and ros2 foxy.
I am following the Nav2 guide but it is not clear if the Odom topics it is automatically populated via the diff_drive gazebo plugin or if I need to create a fake node.

If I need to create a fake node to publish Odom values why the urdf have odom statements in it.

Final question, is Ignition better than Gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401954/how-to-simulate-odom-with-gazebo/) by [niklongstone](https://answers.ros.org/users/102417/niklongstone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2022-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

diff_drive gazebo plugin should be able publish it for you, you can remap the topic depending on your needs, you do not need to write another node. See example file on how to place the plugin tags [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/eddadf5049233f5a38b9d7626e785ebb391bb3a5/gazebo_plugins/test/worlds/gazebo_ros_diff_drive.world#L201)

If you are placing it under urdf, you need to wrap   tags around the plugin.

> Final question, is Ignition better
> than Gazebo?

Speaking really coarsely, yes, it is supposed to be  since its the next generation of Gazebo

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2022-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [niklongstone](https://answers.ros.org/users/102417/niklongstone/) on 2022-06-06**:
So why if I use this repo: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2_tutorials/tree/master/sam_bot_description
I don't see any odom topic. I am not expecting a topic in ros2 but at least I should see one in gazebo.

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2022-06-06**:
You can’t see a topic in gazebo. Do a ros2 topic list and see if there is odom under the /demo namespace

**Comment by [niklongstone](https://answers.ros.org/users/102417/niklongstone/) on 2022-06-06**:
Not sure what went wrong. I've restarted few times Gazebo and now topics are published.
Then it happened again that topic were not published, it looks like some bug when Gazebo spans.